# Summing 46 cells in a column repeatedly, by scenario/year

Tags: excel, sum, aggregate, subtotal

I have the following regional economic data containing estimated output by sector up until 2100, for a variety of growth scenarios.

I want to sum the value of each sector to get a regional output estimate. This requires one to aggregate the output column repeatedly every 46 cells, placing the result in another column (preferably with other information attached too, such as year/scenario ID etc).

As there are >1,000,000 cells it's not a job that can be done by hand. What is the easiest way to sum the regional output across all sectors, by scenario, year and region?

Here's some example data:

```
scenario  year   region_id region_name  sector_id sector_name   value/output
1A_1C_1C    2000    1   London  2   Mining & quarrying      642.2357178
1A_1C_1C    2000    1   London  3   Food, drink & tobacco   1979.741211
1A_1C_1C    2000    1   London  4   Textiles etc            586.706604
1A_1C_1C    2000    1   London  5   Wood & paper            318.1535339
1A_1C_1C    2000    1   London  6   Printing & recording    1749.062012
...             
1A_1C_1C    2000    2   South East  1   Agriculture etc     771.9697876
1A_1C_1C    2000    2   South East  2   Mining & quarrying  542.2153931
1A_1C_1C    2000    2   South East  3   Food, drink & tob.  1990.234009
1A_1C_1C    2000    2   South East  4   Textiles etc        205.3581085
```

EDIT: Can the results please be reported by taking the sum of the output for each region from column 7, and placing them in column 8. Ideally column 9 would then include the specific region name and column 10 would include the specific scenario variant, like this:

```
 Output        Region        Scenario       Year
 XXXXXX        London        1A_1C_1C       2000
 XXXXXX        South East    1A_1C_1C       2000
 ...
 XXXXXX        London        1B_1C_1A       2000
 XXXXXX        South East    1B_1C_1A       2000
 ...
```

EDIT: Add 'year' to output example

Comment: This question needs to provide some idea of how to report the results.

Comment: @Jeeped - Question edited to reflect your comment. Thanks.

Comment: The original narrative also specified the year. Are you looking for a sum across all years or the sum broken down by 'by scenario, year and region'?

Comment: @Jeeped - Again, I made the question more specific. In the first instance I was looking for a method which could be adapted to any combination of criteria, but now I've refined this to the stated format, this answer would be perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do the numerical calculation in Excel. Here's the formula:

```
 =SUM(OFFSET($E$2,(ROW()-2)*46,0,46,1))
```

This sums all values in E2 downwards, every 46 rows using the OFFSET function. The trick is in row() which returns the row number, takes 2 from this number (as I started on C2), and then multiplies this by 46, to shift the SUM function down the column.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are actually asking for an aggregated SQL SELECT statement and perhaps it should be treated as such.

```
Sub Sheets_Group_Having()
    'Dim cnx As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cnx As Object, rs As Object
    Dim sWS As String, sWB As String, sCNX As String, sSQL As String
    Dim ws1TBLaddr As String

    sWB = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sWS = "Source Data Worksheet Name HERE"   `<~~ set the worksheet with the source data
    ws1TBLaddr = WorkSheets(sWS).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0)
    sCNX = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sWB _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cnx = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cnx.Open sCNX

    sSQL = "SELECT SUM(w1.[value/output]), w1.[region_name], w1.[scenario], w1.[year] FROM [" & sWS & "$" & ws1TBLaddr & "] w1"
    sSQL = sSQL & " GROUP BY w1.[region_id], w1.[region_name], w1.[scenario], w1.[year]"
    sSQL = sSQL & " ORDER BY w1.[region_id], w1.[scenario]"
    'Debug.Print sSQL

    rs.Open sSQL, cnx

    With Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        .Name = "Summary Data"
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, 4) = Array("output", "region", "scenario", "year")
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    cnx.Close: Set cnx = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jeeped. I'm not familiar with SQL, but really should be, so I'm going to attempt to use the code you've provided. Thank you.